# How to sum up this inverse function $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2r}{1+2r^4}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function, trigonometric-series

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2r}{1+2r^4}\right)$$

So I really couldn't get started. I know that it is probably of form 
$$ \tan^{-1}(y) - \tan^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y-x}{1+xy}\right)$$ , but I couldn't bring it in that form. The denominator won't let me . Help please...

Comment: Hint: Try $(x,y) = (f(r-1),f(r))$ where $f(r) = 2r^2+2r+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave it to you to prove by induction that the partial sum is $\arctan\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$, so the limit is $\pi/4$. One approach to obtaining this partial sum is that of @achillehui's telescope, viz. $$\left[\arctan(2r^2+2r+1)\right]_{-1}^n=\arctan\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+1}.$$

Edit: just to spell it out, the definition $f(r):=\arctan(2r^2+2r+1)$ gives $$\sum_{r=0}^n\arctan\frac{2r}{1+2r^4}=\sum_{r=0}^n\left(f(r)-f(r-1)\right)=f(n)-f(-1),$$where the second $=$ can be proven by induction; this is the basis of any proof with telescoping series. In particular $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n)-f(-1))=\arctan\infty-\arctan1=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: How , please explain...

Comment: @user232243 Which part needs explaining? You already demonstrated an understanding of how the telescoping works.

Comment: I have not been taught about telescopic series as such you see... I have only been introduced this to me in  the form of questions ( which cover various types of questions) , rather than any formal/proper theory

Comment: How did you figure it out..?? How to divide it. Or is it something that comes through experience ??

Comment: @user232243 I've just edited my answer to show how the telescoping works. My own approach to finding the partial sum was to calculate the first few terms to spot a pattern, using $\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$. I don't know how achille hui came up with their idea, but it was likely by doubling the numerator and denominator and using a famous result due to Sophie Germain, $$a^4+4b^4=(a^2+2b^2)^2-(2ab)^2=\prod_\pm(a^2+2ab+2b^2)$$(in this case with $a=1,\,b=r$). So yes, it comes down to experience.

Comment: Thank You So Much